# problems with Wordpress character encoding

Tags: wordpress

i have problem with my wp. Generally it shows "&curren" sign not text.

I have to use XML integration link with WP all import.
Propper link:

https://api.ikonka.com.pl/api2/index.php/request/?format=xml&hash=a5894fd3a6175f38060436bb68e58f9c9a8229aa&variant=b&lang=pl&currency=PLN

wp outputs:

[https://api.ikonka.com.pl/api2/index.php/request/?format=xml&hash=a5894fd3a6175f38060436bb68e58f9c9a8229aa&variant=b&lang=pl¤cy=PLN](https://api.ikonka.com.pl/api2/index.php/request/?format=xml&hash=a5894fd3a6175f38060436bb68e58f9c9a8229aa&variant=b&lang=pl%C2%A4cy=PLN)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH4ub.png)

Please help me to solve this problem.

PS. Wordpress wasn't updated or anything changed, it was working fine. I really don't know it just stopped

I tried :

Reinstalling Wp,
checked link in Wp all import sandbox (works fine)

also:

Use the entity for & itself;

'page.com?a=1&currentPage=2'

Or use your variable at the beginning so no & is required:

'page.com?currentPage=2&a=1'

nothing helped